# Is an infinite loop impossible in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter

For some reason I'm trying to conceive a simple script that can retrieve tweets from a given twitter account and then make something with it (that's not really the relevant part). Following a friend's advice I tried to do it in nodejs. He helped me a little (gave me some code actually) and I managed to get something working. So if I want to retrieve all tweets from one user it works perfectly fine. But actually what I would like is to loop and check the new tweets. But when I wrap my code in a simple while(1) (and modify it as needed) it doesn't do anything. So here's my code :

```
var tweetFetcher = require('./tweetFetcher');
var codeExtractor = require('./codeExtractor');
var open = require('open');
var fs = require('fs');
var filters = [filter1, filter2];
var hasfirstpart = 0;
var code = "";
var tweets;
var i = 0;
while(1){
    tweets = tweetFetcher.getFrom('twitteraccount', function(tweets) {
        console.log(tweets[0]);
        if(tweets[0].indexOf(filters[hasfirstpart]) > -1){
            code += codeExtractor.extract(tweets[0]).substring(3);
            hasfirstpart = (hasfirstpart+1)%2;  
            console.log(code);
        }
        if(hasfirstpart == 0 && code != ""){
            ...
        }
    });
}



var parser = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');


exports.getFrom = function(username, cb) {
    var url = "http://twitter.com/"+username;

    request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
        var $ = parser.load(body);
        var tweets = [];
        $('.ProfileTweet-text').each(function() {
            tweets.push($(this).text());
        });

        if(typeof cb == 'function') {
            cb(tweets);
        }
    });
}
```

Do you have any idea why it cannot be wrapped in a loop ? Thanks in advance for your response :)

Comment: As it's written, your program looks a bit like a denial-of-service attack.  Sending HTTP requests to a web server without any delay is bad practice, and will most likely get your IP address blocked in short order.

Comment: You're right I noticed it as well and tried to use sleep but couldn't install it - not working for some reason

Comment: The thing is, even if I put a busy loop instead at the end it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `while (1)` in node.js with IO operations, because it will block event loop and prevent all callbacks from being called. If you want to do something forever you need to use recursion instead:

```
function doThing () {
    tweetFetcher.getFrom('twitteraccount', function(tweets) {
        ...

        doThing();
    });
}
```

Comment: Won't the stack eventually overflow with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, I recommend using `setInterval(function, time)`. You can stop the interval at any time by using `clearInterval(unterval)`.